# Unable to update database with Firebird Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I have a .Net 7 application that uses scaffolded Identity. I was successfully able to build the scaffolded database using SQLite - I now want to try using Firebird.

I get following error:

> Method not found:
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.IModelInitializedConvention>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ConventionSet.get_ModelInitializedConventions()'.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74369798/how-to-solve-method-not-found-system-collections-generic-ilist1microsoft-enti), I installed latest EntityFrameworkCore libraries:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird" Version="9.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.3">
```

Still no help - and it doesn't seem to be related to my connection string (but maybe - so I post it just in case):

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "MyContextConnection": "datasource=localhost;database=C:/MyPath/MyDB.FDB;user id=******;password=*******;port number=3050;dialect=3;pooling=True;server type=0;character set=UTF8;connection lifetime=15;min pool size=0;max pool size=50;packet size=8192;wire crypt=Enabled",
"MyDBProvider": "Firebird"
}
```

Am I missing something out there?

Comment: EF 7 is not yet suported by Firebird,see  https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/NETProvider/issues/1083

Comment: ok so I need to downgrade the project to EF 6, then initialize the DB, can you confirm?

Comment: I'm still on NET 3.1 :(  because of this issue since .net 5 https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/NETProvider/issues/1021